# Python getting cookies from webpage set by javascript without selenium

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have been working on an automation script that requires a cookie value set by javascript within the webpage being requested in my script. Is there a way to get the cookies set by the javascript without using selenium? In my testing selenium is much too slow even with a headless browser. I need a better (quicker) method in getting these cookies. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request`'s `Session` object handles traditional cookies automatically for you.

If these cookies are set by JavaScript, then you'll have to look at the JS code to "emulate" them and manually set them, but it should be possible. Python won't run the JS code on its own, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cookies can be read with Javascript using

```
document.cookie
```

Since there can be many values inside the cookies, you can either write your own functions to gather values from it, or use a library, like [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Read more here:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp